# Как быть с относительными путями когда заливаешь сайт на хостинг и когда открываешь html файл в браузере?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так! Я понимаю, что если прописать для background-image путь такой - "../img/image.png", то картинка будет отображаться если я открою страницу на локальном хосте, но если закину на гит или на хостинг, то не будет. А если написать "img/image.png", то будет всё наоборот. На локальном не отображается, а на гит или на хостинге всё ок!
Как быть в таком случае? Качать VSCode и ставить на него плагин live server?

Comment: у меня есть вот такой репозиторий https://github.com/mihinov/mihinov.github.io, а вот его github pages https://mihinov.github.io/, всё нормально с путями, вообще проблем никаких не возникало

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Возможно из-за того, что у все папки не вместе с index.html а у тебя индекс в корне и всё остальное в "под корне" так сказать.

Comment: Да нет, у меня это будет работать и если изображение будет даже не в папке

Comment: @МихаилКамахин хмммм. Ну смотри, вот ссылка на страницу - http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Roderen/ladesign/blob/main/index.html
И вот ссылка на репозиторий - https://github.com/Roderen/ladesign
Ну точно такое же как и у тебя, но картинка (если пропишу путь в css) не отображается. Если уберу "../" то будет работать, но не будет работать на локал хосте...хд хз что и как((

Comment: mihinov.github.io/news , смотри, это не ссылка на html файл, ты не должен открывать html файл

Comment: Тебе надо github pages включить

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Так даже если взять не гитхаб, а обычный хостинг (покупной) на который я залью всё это, то всё равно не будет работать, так как нужно убарть "../" но в том то и дело, что без "../" не будет работь на локальном, но будет на обычно.

Comment: У меня всё везде работает )

Comment: @МихаилКамахин ну это у тебя, а это я ))

Comment: Dunker через этот сервис у меня тоже не показываются картинки некоторые http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mihinov/mihinov.github.io/master/index.html,
потому что гитхаб многое запрещает делать сторонним сайтам с их ресурсами

Comment: Dunker у меня твой код работает локально, если открыть index.html и если запустить через liveserver

Comment: htmlpreview.github.io это не сервис от гитхаба, и он криво работает, поэтому надо пользоваться github pages, официальным инструментом от гитхаба

Comment: @МихаилКамахин задам вопрос в разы короче:
Если я буду заливать сайт на ПОКУПНОЙ хостинг, то мне нужно будет убирать "../" перед путями для bg-image?

Comment: Проверьте, возьмите хостинг бесплатный, beget, например